# What is the best way to change a column type in ClickHouse table?

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

What is the best way to change a column type in ClickHouse table from Int32 to Int64? The table size is about 5Gb (handreds of millions lines). The column is NOT NULL, the engine is ReplacingMergeTree. The column also is in the ORDER BY in the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: You can't alter a primary key column. Create a new table with the desired primary key, then copy the old data into the new table. (5GB is nothing in ClickHouse - it won't even take that long)

Answer (score 4):

One way to change the column type from int32 to int64 is with the MODIFY COLUMN command in the ALTER TABLE. for a large table is going to take a long time. You can change the order of the columns using the FIRST or AFTER. but you should specify the column type in this senario.

as an example, you can write :
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY COLUMN value Int64 FIRST;

Comment: Ali's answer looks good here - just wanted to add a note that since this is a mutation operation, you can also monitor the mutation until complete - 5GB is not a large amount of data in ClickHouse so shouldn't take too long: 

SELECT count(*)
FROM system.mutations
WHERE is_done = 0;